# Unable to parse xml data using pandas method read.xml()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xml, xml-parsing

```
xml = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <doc:data xmlns:doc="https://example.com">
      <doc:row>
        <doc:shape value="triangle" />
        <doc:degrees value="180" />
        <doc:sides value="3.0"/>
      </doc:row>
      <doc:row>
        <doc:shape value="triangle" />
        <doc:degrees value="180" />
        <doc:sides value="3.0"/>
      </doc:row>
      <doc:row>
        <doc:shape value="triangle" />
        <doc:degrees value="180" />
        <doc:sides value="3.0"/>
      </doc:row>
    </doc:data>'''

df = pd.read_xml(xml,
                 xpath="//doc:row",
                 namespaces={"doc": "https://example.com"})
print(df)
```

I am getting the output as follows:

```
shape   degrees sides
0   NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN
```

Th expected output is:

```
shape   degrees sides
0   triangle    180 3.0
1   triangle    180 3.0
2   triangle    180 3.0
```

The values for each tag are present in the "value = ".Had it not been in the value tag then the data is loading properly. please help in getting the respective values for each in the above xml.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact expected output given your xml? Your values seem to be identical in all rows.

Comment: I think `read_xml` gets contents between tags (like `<doc:shape>"triangle"</doc:shape>`), not attributes (like `value="triangle"`) but you have empty tags. You will have to get this using `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` and use `for`-loops.

Comment: @JackFleeting
the expected output is updated in question

Comment: @furas 
how can we do it using the above method. read_xml()

Comment: you can't use `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` with `read_xml` - it may need to use only `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the columns beforehand you can use kwarg `iterparse` instead of `xpath`:

```
df = pd.read_xml("example.xml",
                 iterparse = {"row": ["value", "value", "value"]},
                 names = ["shape", "degrees", "sides"]
                 )
```

Output:

```
      shape  degrees  sides
0  triangle      180    3.0
1  triangle      180    3.0
2  triangle      180    3.0
```

Edit: the above solution isn't robust at all since messing with the order of the subelements will mess up the data (problem here being the identical attribute names `value` of the subelements). If the order might change, you can still build your columns one after the other and concatenate them:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_xml("example.xml",
                    iterparse = {name: ["value"]},
                    names = [name])
                    for name in ["shape", "degrees", "sides"]
    ], axis=1
)
```

No idea how it would perform on bigger file though...

Comment: df = pd.read_xml(xml,iterparse = {"row": ["value", "value", "value"]},names = ["shape", "degrees", "sides"])

Comment: I am getting TypeError: read_xml() got an unexpected keyword argument 'iterparse'

Comment: It was introduced in [pandas 1.5.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html). Also it seems to only work while reading from a file and not a string.

Comment: maybe it needs to use `io.String(xml)` to create file-like object in memory and use `pd.read_xml(io.String(xml), ...)`